# Как организовать вывод массива?

Tags: массивы, c

Подскажите, как действовать, если дан массив (например n) длиной 32 элемента, произвольно заполненный нулями и единицами, и требуется вывести содержимое в виде:

> n(1) = "Первые четыре элемента массива"
> n(2) = "Вторые четыре элемента массива"
> ...
> n(8) = "Последние четыре элемента массива"

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ничего не понял.  Куда вывести? В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю зачем два цикла...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int size = 32;
  int arr[size];
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0;i<size;i++){
    arr[i] = 1;
  }
  for(i = 0;i<size;i++){
    if(!(i%4)){
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая штука как вложенность циклов. Так вот идея: первый цикл перебирает сегменты массива, а второй все элементы данного сегмента.

```
int segs = n/4;
for(int i = 0; i < segs; i++ ) {
    std::cout << "n(" << i+1 << ") = ";
    for(int j = 0; j < 4 && segs * i + j < n; j++) {
        std::cout << mas[segs * i + j] << ' ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, можно обойтись и одним циклом :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n[32] = {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
             1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
             0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,
             1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1};

    int i, k = 1;
    for (i = 0; i< sizeof(n)/sizeof(int); i = i+4,k++) {
        printf("n(%1d) = \"%1d%1d%1d%1d\"\n",k,n[i],n[i+1],n[i+2],n[i+3]);  
    }   
}
```

На выходе получаем:

```
n(1) = "0111"
n(2) = "0000"
n(3) = "1110"
n(4) = "0110"
n(5) = "0110"
n(6) = "0011"
n(7) = "1111"
n(8) = "0001"
```

Answer (score -1):

малость непонятно:
дан массив(например n) 32 элемента, это как? ну да ладно)
цифры 32 и 8 выдуманы, так что можете использовать sizeof главное чтоб делилось на 4 :)

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
 int array[32];
 int result[8];
 int j = 0;
 int m = 0;
 for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
     array[i] = i; // заполним массив

  }
 for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    m = m + 4;
     for(j; j < m; j++) {
         result[i] = array [j]; // не правильно, в плюсах не силен, данные суммируются

      }

  } 
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    std::cout << result[i] << std::endl; //покажем массив

  }

}
```